# call async function onclick button

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, exceljs

I try to call a function from a button in the HTML

HTML:

```
<body>
   <button id="file" onclick="print()">FILE</button>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs')

const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

async function print(){
   var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
   const worksheet = await workbook.csv.readFile('Data.csv');
   for (let index = 0; index < worksheet.columns.length; index++) {
       let text = worksheet.getCell(letters[index]+'1').value
       if(text != null){
          console.log(text)  
       }
   }
}
```

But the console doesn't print anything.

If I call the function from the JS it works, but I need it to be with the button.

Comment: Could you explain the variable `letters` please?

Comment: Don't call your function `print()`, it conflicts with the built-in `window.print()`.

Comment: what are you using to bundle this for the browser?  browserify?  you need to export the function and expose it in the window context.  why are you using onclick="" and not addEventListener?

Comment: @AndrésMuñoz **letters** is an array containing the letters of the columns, I already added it to the question.

Barmar, I already changed the function name, but still don't print the data.

Comment: @user120242 I'm using Node and Electron, at fisrt use addEventListener, but it does not work, I thought about changing it for onclik, but neither way prints the data.